# Angular: routerLinkActive does not work properly

Tags: angular

I have two simple pages: Home and About. I also have a menu array in my `AppComponent`:

```
menu = [
  {path: '', title: 'Home'},
  {path: 'about', title: 'About'}
];
```

Styles:

```
.active {
  color: red;
}

.blue {
  color: blue;
}
```

And View:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of menu" [routerLink]="item.path" routerLinkActive="active"
      [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
    <span routerLinkActive="blue">+</span>{{item.title}}
  </li>
</ul>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

When I'm navigating to the pages, I want link become red and plus sign become blue. But when I'm on the About page, Home link's plus sign is also blue:

[image: Capture]

What can I do? I cannot style plus sign in other way, only with `routerLinkActive` (in my real project everything is much more complicated).

Comment: You used routerLinkActiveOptions on one, but not on the other.

Comment: Why not just use css. `li.active span`

Comment: @JbNizet, yes, my bad. Now all works. Thank you so much!

Comment: You should definitely follow penleychan's advice.

Comment: @JbNizet, I use Font Awesome icons (SVG). I cannot style them in that way. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56828270/angular-with-fontawesome-cannot-style-path

Comment: Regarding to that question link, you can actually. You need to use `ng-deep`

Comment: @penleychan, I will definitely try. Thank you!